# AvalonDock dock panels

Tags: avalondock

I have created the dockable panel using avalondock but by default the panel is coming on right side. How to move the panel to left side?

```
    <avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion">
        <avalonDock:LayoutRoot  >
            <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane/>
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="150"  >
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable local:AvalonDockRegion.Name="SampleToolRegion"/>

                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="150" >
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable local:AvalonDockRegion.Name="SampleRibbonRegion"  />
                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>

           </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
        </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand your question.
if the 2 panes are sorted from right to left Try to set the flow direction of the docking manager to left to right

```
<avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
    <avalonDock:LayoutRoot  >
        <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane/>
            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="150"  >
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable local:AvalonDockRegion.Name="SampleToolRegion"/>

            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
            <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="150" >
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable local:AvalonDockRegion.Name="SampleRibbonRegion"  />
            </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>

       </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
    </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
</avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 

```html
    <avalonDock:DockingManager x:Name="dockingManager" cal:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion">
        <avalonDock:LayoutRoot  >
            <avalonDock:LayoutPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="150"  >
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable local:AvalonDockRegion.Name="SampleToolRegion"/>

                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
                <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane DockWidth="150" >
                    <avalonDock:LayoutAnchorable local:AvalonDockRegion.Name="SampleRibbonRegion"  />
                </avalonDock:LayoutAnchorablePane>
<avalonDock:LayoutDocumentPane/>
           </avalonDock:LayoutPanel>
        </avalonDock:LayoutRoot>
    </avalonDock:DockingManager>
```

Just changed the sequence of LayoutDocumentPane and LayoutAnchorablePane.
Hope I have understood your question correctly.